# Cassandra update previous rows after insert

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cqlsh

I have this schema in cassandra:

```
create table if not exists 
converstation_events(
    timestamp timestamp, 
    sender_id bigint, 
    conversation_id bigint, 
    message_type varchar, 
    message text, 
    primary key ((conversation_id), sender_id, message_type, timestamp));
```

And there is a message_type with value conversation_ended, is there a way to denormalise the data so I can do queries on those conversations that have already ended?

I've thought about having an extra field that can be updated by a trigger when a conversation_ended message hits the system, does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra you need to model your data in a way the answers your questions.  It's not like a RDBMS where you create you model first then create your queries.  So think backwards...

When you do a query in cassandra (for the most part...) you need to query by the primary key and you can use your clustering key(s) to filter or a select ranges. a [great post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) on it.

Your `converstation_events` table will give you answers about a conversation, filtering by sender, type and time.  ** if you want to filter by time you must include `sender_id` and `message_type` in the query.

But you want all conversations of a given type so you'll need another table to answer this query.  If you want all the conversation that are `conversation_ended` you could create a second table to map message type to conversation, like-

```
conversation_by_message_type (
    message_type varchar, 
    conversation_id bigint, 
    timestamp timestamp, 
    primary key ((message_type), timestamp, conversation_id));
```

On the client side you'll have to add a record to `conversation_by_message_type` anytime you insert a converstation_events event with a given `message_type` that you might want to look up.  I have `timestamp` in this table so you can sort or filter by time or `time` and `conversation_id`.

To find all the ended conversations you could do queries like

```
<ids> = select conversation_id from conversation_by_message_type where message_type = 'conversation_ended'

select * from conversation_events where conversation_id IN (<ids>)
```

Comment: what i need is to be able to query all messages where conversation has ended. (like a version of: select * from messages where conversation_id in (select convertation_id where message_type = 'conversation_ended'); and since you can't do this i  Cassandra, I was thinking to add another field to the rows that get's updated when a conversation_ended event is inserted. like 'is_ended' or something like that

Comment: With cassandra you need to define your queries (questions) first and the design your model to be able to answer those questions.  The partition key part of the primary key controls what node your data is on.  You want to stay from cluster scans - this is why the 2nd index probably isn't a good idea.  Using a 2nd table (a common thing to do....) like above would let you do what you want. You just have to do it on the client side

Comment: but i still have the same issue. on client side idk when that message will be from a closed conversation. should i add a field 'is_closed: to the schema and insert them to false and then when the conversation_close event gets to the system update is_closed = true where conversation_id= conversation_id from closed event? does this make sense? can i so it with a trigger?

Comment: no... that doesn't make sense.  it sounds like you're hung up trying to make cassandra act like something like MySql.  you can't really filter on a non key field with the exception of a 2nd index.  you need an 'conversation_by_message_type' index to lookup the message of a given type.   i'm going to expand my answer a bit..